# plsql - Oracle select with collections

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two number collections, one containing n ids and one containing n values. I also have a select statement containing n records. Now, I want to join them together. 
Intuitively I tried to do something like this:

```
select * from
(
  select t.stat                       StatNr
       , t.statNr                     StatValue
       , t.statName                   statusName
    from myTable t
   where t.nr = 1234
   order by ...
) status,
(
  select statId.v   StatNr
       , statVal.v  StatValue
  from
  (
  select column_value v
       , rownum       r  
    from table( numberCollection( 98, 45, 66, 153, 103, 67, 27 ) ) 
  ) statId,
  (
  select column_value v
       , rownum       r  
    from table( numberCollection(  1,  2,  1,   1,   3,  2,  2 ) )
  ) statVal
  where statId.r = statVal.r
) statusNew
where status.StatNr = statusNew.StatNr
  and status.StatValue <> statusNew.StatValue
```

So, the select statement without number collection returns something like this:

```
ID  VALUE   NAME          
98  1       some varchar
153 1       some varchar
66  1       some varchar
27  3       some varchar
67  4       some varchar
45  1       some varchar
103 1       some varchar
```

And I want to add the corresponding id's and values from my collections to see if the value row from my table is different to the value row from my collection, and then return the name.

So, the result looks like this:

```
ID  VALUE   NAME            ID  VALUE
98  1       some varchar    98  1
153 1       some varchar    153 1
66  1       some varchar    66  1
27  3       some varchar    27  2
67  4       some varchar    67  2
45  1       some varchar    45  2
103 1       some varchar    103 3
```

Where the former id and value are from the table and the latter id and value columns are from the collections.

So the where clause at the end:

```
and status.StatValue <> statusNew.StatValue
```

would give me the records with changed values, returning row 4 - 7.

Now, this looks a bit ugly from my point of view. Especially the where clause where I check for the rownum. Anyway I'm relatively new to Oracle, is there a downside to this or a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by  `join them together`. Can you post the original data structure and the expected result

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have your matching-information and your compare-data in two independent numberCollections, the only way to synchronize these two lists is by position, which here is the ROWNUM.

But you can make your SQL a bit more readable by using the WITH-clause:

```
WITH comparedata AS (
 SELECT statid.v StatNr, statval.v StatValue
   FROM (
       select column_value v
            , rownum       r  
         from table( numberCollection( 98, 45, 66, 153, 103, 67, 27 ) ) 
       ) statId,
       (
       select column_value v
            , rownum       r  
         from table( numberCollection(  1,  2,  1,   1,   3,  2,  2 ) )
       ) statVal
       where statId.r = statVal.r
  )
select t.statNr   
     , t.statValue
     , t.statName 
  from myTable t
  JOIN comparedata d ON d.StatNr ON t.StatNr
 where t.nr = 1234
  and status.StatValue <> statusNew.StatValue
order by ...
```

Here you define a named subquery called "comparedata" with the result of the mapped numberCollections.
After this, you use "comparedata" as any view or table in the JOIN-clause with your real table.

Other ways to achieve your goal will end up in more code (like a routine, that splits strings of a format like "id=value;[id=value;...]" into a collection with two columns ID and VALUE. 
But if you have to do such jobs more often, you may consider, if it´s worth to spend the time in creating such a function.