# Way to select columns with different values in oracle sql

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, oracle

I am developing a node/react application.

I have three sets of sql queries.

1. Select all columns before update
2. Update a column
3. Select all columns after update
4. ?

How can I retrieve the exact column difference between the results of first and third sql queries?

```
(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
T1- SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;
T2- UPDATE MY_TABLE SET COLUMN1='a' WHERE COLUMN3= 'b' FROM MY_TABLE;
T3- SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;
T4- Difference between T3 and T1 queries (COLUMN1 should be the result)
```

Thank you

Comment: You can collect updates with `RETURNING INTO` Clause https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm

Comment: Hi Serg, I use it from oracledb add-on from node js

Comment: It's a bit tricky but you can SELECT from collections https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172682/plsql-oracle-select-with-collections so returning a regular dataset to js client

Comment: @Serg: `returning into` can only be used in PL/SQL, not in regular SQL queries.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I assume oracledb add-on for node.js allows to execute PL/SQL blocks and procs https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#plsqlexecution. Never tried it for myself though.

Comment: The short answer is your T4 is impossible to deliver using default tables. so, instead of presenting your guess at a solution -perhaps you should explain the requirement you're trying to implement and the constraints you're working under.

Comment: I'm with @Serg, seems like RETURNING INTO is the best choice unless it doesn't meet your needs. Also, why do you think it's only supported with PL/SQL? Here's an example from the documentation that only uses SQL: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#dmlreturn

Answer (score 0):

One evident alternative to complex database-specific features is using good old timestamps...

1. Add a new column "LAST_MODIFIED" and modify T2 to udpate the timestamp
2. T4 -> select the rows whose timestamp have been updated

Another evident solution is to query for those records which don't have the right value (COLUMN3= 'b') before you run the update, store this result set in a temp table in database or in memory depending on your specific requirements, this result set is used to run the update afterwards, and the final report.